# Proving something is an inner product

Tags: inner-products

I am faced with the following question:

[image]

Prove that this is an inner product on V.

I understand to show something is an inner product I must verify the following conditions:

1. $\langle\,f,g\rangle = \overline{\langle\,g,f\rangle}$ (Conjugate symmetry)
2. $\langle\,\overline\alpha (f + g),h\rangle = \overline\alpha(\langle\,f,h\rangle + \langle\,g,h\rangle)$ (Linearity in the first argument)
3. $\langle\,f,f\rangle \ge 0$ with equality iff $f=0$

(Note: conditions (1) and (2) are slightly different to usual as we are dealing with complex numbers)

I have seen other examples of this being done, however, I am not sure how to do it in this particular case. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific about where you're running into trouble? If you tried copying what you've seen for similar examples, then where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @James, this is one of those grind-em-out problems, but straightforward. Write out the products and compute the traces. If it's any comfort for you, all of this holds for $n \times n$ matrices too.

Comment: Shouldn't 2. be $\langle\bar{\alpha}f+\bar{\beta}g,\,h\rangle=\bar{\alpha}\langle f,\,h\rangle+\bar{\beta}\langle g,\,h\rangle$?

Comment: @Aruralreader sorry I don't fully understand what you mean by this?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I got stuck at knowing where to begin. The other examples didn't involve complex numbers and were more straightforward.

Comment: @James Then try first the real case with simple transpose. If you handle the matrices as $4$ dimensional vectors, what expression do you get for ${\rm tr}(A^TB)$?

Comment: Show that it is the same as the 'usual' inner product if you write out the matrix elements as one big long vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you have $A$ and $B$, compute $C_{ij} := \sum_k A^*_{ki}B_{kj}$. That's what $A^\dagger B$ is all about, and with it you can compute its trace, giving
\begin{align}
\langle A, B\rangle &= \sum_{i} A^*_{ki}B_{ki}.
\end{align}

Straightforward this way to work through each of the conditions you list for an inner product.